# Uploading app into App Store it will takes 7 to 8 days.Is there any solution for minimum days its upload into App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone

uploading an iOS application in App Store it will takes 7 to 8 days.Is there any way it will take minimum days ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a good reason to convince Apple, then YES. You can ask for an expedite review. You can find the option in developer.apple.com. But, as I have said, you must convince Apple about the urgency. And more, next time you need a expedite review for a new version or for a new app, they will reject it. They never accept two expedite review request in a period of one year from a developer.

Comment: I have a comment. Today developer.apple.com is down 'cause of WWDC. So at this moment there are no other way. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no other way. If you want to upload your app to iOS App Store you have to wait for Apple to review your App.

Answer (score 0):

There is no set time-limit for the app approval process. it can take anywhere between 5 days and 4 weeks.There’s nothing technical you can do to get your app reviewed faster.

but nevertheless here is some [Tricks and Tips](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/ios-app-store-approval-tips-and-tricks) for App approval.